# Restore deleted default folders

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, default-settings, home-directory

I was tinkering with my new laptop and, on purpose, deleted those default folders in my "home" directory: "My Music", "Links", "Favorites". This, because, i decided i wanted all my data on another partition, leaving C: only for applications and configs files.

But now, some of the explorer functionalities are gone: i cannot use the Favorites tree in the left side pane, also discovered that "My Documents" stores some PowerShell config file.

I feel like i misunderstood this folders' purpose and by deleting them, provoked some Explorer instability. Is there any way to restore them? I do not seem to find it.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 4):

Check this step-by-step [Restoring the Default Location of Windows 7 User Folders](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18583-user-folders-restore-default-location.html)